# How do I include the result of a token as a parameter for another (custom) token?

Tags: tokens

I'm writing a module with custom tokens.

I need a token that generates a hash based on three other tokens: user id, poll id and (poll) option id. The idea is that a user gets links to vote by email and she can vote just by hitting the link, but to authenticate the link I need to generate a unique, checkable hash in it. So I should be able to write a mass mail with tokens that would contain links like

```
<a href="http:/mysite/votingpage/[user:uid]/[poll:nid]/[poll:option:id]/[hash(user, poll, option)]>Option text</a>
```

(I know the tokens are not right, but you get what I mean).

Then I would check if the hash is true for the user, poll and option, and save the vote if true.

The problem is I can't get the token for `hash` to be computed from the other tokens, I don't know how to go about it. Maybe I don't understand how the 'need-data' field in the hook_token_info function works, or maybe it isn't possible out of the box.

Any ideas?